# Compiling SDL 2 alongside my own source files

Tags: c, swift, sdl-2

Due to a compilation bug I cannot correctly use the SDL dynamically linked, I don't prefer to go with the static linking route as I'm not sure of how well implemented this is in the language I am using.

That's why I would like to compile the SDL 2 source files manually, I simply used the files present under /include and /src in the official repo, but at compile time I get this error:

```
In file included from /Users/adtrevor/CompileSDL/Sources/SDL/src/video/qnx/video.c:23:
/Users/adtrevor/CompileSDL/Sources/SDL/src/video/qnx/sdl_qnx.h:26:10: fatal error: 'screen/screen.h' file not found
#include <screen/screen.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/adtrevor/CompileSDL/Sources/SDL/src/video/qnx/keyboard.c:26:
/Users/adtrevor/CompileSDL/Sources/SDL/src/video/qnx/sdl_qnx.h:26:10: fatal error: 'screen/screen.h' file not found
#include <screen/screen.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
In file included from /Users/adtrevor/CompileSDL/Sources/SDL/src/video/qnx/gl.c:23:
/Users/adtrevor/CompileSDL/Sources/SDL/src/video/qnx/sdl_qnx.h:26:10: fatal error: 'screen/screen.h' file not found
#include <screen/screen.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

I know it is possible to do that since the official website mentions it, but I don't know at all what steps I should follow in order to make it work correctly?

**EDIT :**
Here is the sample repo: https://github.com/adtrevor/compileSDL

Comment: Could you provide a link to the github?  This is happening because `screen/screen.h` isn't found within any of the include paths passed to your compiler.  Also, what compiler/toolchain are you using.

Comment: @AndyJ Thank you for your reply. Here is the repo : https://github.com/adtrevor/compileSDL
I am using the Swift compiler, that uses Clang when it needs to build C code.

Comment: @AndyJ I guess the biggest issue is also that it will try to compile for all platforms, but I don't what I should do. It's especially confusing that the website mentions the possibility of compiling the files directly with your project but that there is absolutely no info anywhere on how to do it.

Comment: Are you sure about `<>`; seems like `""` would be more appropriate, but I can't find it on `compileSDL`.

Comment: @NeilEdelman This is the code straight from the SDL source so I think this is right. I am sorry about the missing parts of the code, Inwill update it. My biggest concern is that I don’t know what to compile and what to exclude as this source code includes all possible plateforms

Comment: I've never actually successfully compiled SDL2; I gave up compiling and went with the binaries.

Comment: All the steps for compilation are in INSTALL.txt...

Comment: Is it reasonable to install SDL normally and have your library use it as a systemLibrary target instead of a normal library target?

Comment: @bscothern There is a bug with it on Ubuntu 18.04 unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

SDL is a cross-platform library, and its unlikely that you want to compile all of the source files in order to get the functionality that you need.  Usually you run `configure` / `make`, and it will make the decisions on what to build/not build.

You mention that you are building the source files yourself; so you may want to obverse the SDL build and try to capture the same files.  In regards to your error, QNX is the Blackberry operating system-- so depending on your use-cases you can avoid building everything under `SDL/src/video/qnx/*` since you don't have those operating system headers anyway.

SDL should build the static libraries by default anyhow.  Consider doing a regular build and using `sdl-config --static-libs` to find out which static libraries you should link with.